# Why does scalac seem to expand implicits too far?

Tags: scala, implicit

I am trying to diagnose a compiler error which is caused by diverging implicit expansion errors.

Here is what I am seeing:

```
❯ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_252).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :settings -Xlog-implicits

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Invariant[A]
trait Covariant[+A]
trait Foo

implicit def invariantTuple1[T1: Invariant]: Invariant[Tuple1[T1]] = ???

implicit def invariantFoo: Invariant[Foo] = ???

def a = implicitly[Invariant[Foo]]

implicit def covariant[A: Invariant]: Covariant[A] = ???

def b = implicitly[Covariant[Foo]]

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


def b = implicitly[Covariant[Foo]]
                  ^
<pastie>:13: invariantTuple1 is not a valid implicit value for Invariant[T1] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: diverging implicit expansion for type Invariant[T1]
starting with method invariantFoo

def b = implicitly[Covariant[Foo]]
                  ^
<pastie>:13: invariantFoo is not a valid implicit value for Invariant[T1] because:
diverging implicit expansion for type Invariant[T1]
starting with method invariantTuple1

def b = implicitly[Covariant[Foo]]
                  ^
```

(remaining output elided for clarity)

I want to know why specifically does this the compiler output these particular diverging implicit expansion messages?

Take this one first:

```
invariantTuple1 is not a valid implicit value for Invariant[T1] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: diverging implicit expansion for type Invariant[T1]
starting with method invariantFoo
```

What does the "starting with method invariantFoo" mean here?

From what I can tell from the start of the message is that it is trying to find an implicit parameter for `invariantTuple1` of type `Invariant[T1]`. Then what? It is trying to see if `invariantFoo` is a match? It's not a match but it certainly doesn't diverge. The "starting with" part sounds like that is where it starts but `invariantFoo` doesn't have any implicit parameters so why would that need to look any further?

The next one is also confusing:

```
invariantFoo is not a valid implicit value for Invariant[T1] because:
diverging implicit expansion for type Invariant[T1]
starting with method invariantTuple1
```

`invariantFoo` should be a valid implicit value for `Invariant[T1]` (assuming `T1` is `Foo`). So how can `invariantFoo` diverge when it has not implicit parameters?

Comment: See my comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62335096/why-do-both-of-these-implicits-match-when-only-one-of-them-would-type-check