# Why do both of these implicits match when only one of them would type check?

Tags: scala, implicit

I am trying to diagnose a compiler error which is caused by diverging implicit expansion errors.

Here is what I am seeing:

```
❯ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_252).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :settings -Xlog-implicits

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Invariant[A]
trait Covariant[+A]
trait Foo

implicit def invariantTuple1[T1: Invariant]: Invariant[Tuple1[T1]] = ???

implicit def invariantFoo: Invariant[Foo] = ???

def a = implicitly[Invariant[Foo]]

implicit def covariant[A: Invariant]: Covariant[A] = ???

def b = implicitly[Covariant[Foo]]

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


def b = implicitly[Covariant[Foo]]
                  ^
<pastie>:13: invariantTuple1 is not a valid implicit value for Invariant[T1] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: diverging implicit expansion for type Invariant[T1]
starting with method invariantFoo

def b = implicitly[Covariant[Foo]]
                  ^
<pastie>:13: invariantFoo is not a valid implicit value for Invariant[T1] because:
diverging implicit expansion for type Invariant[T1]
starting with method invariantTuple1

def b = implicitly[Covariant[Foo]]
                  ^
<pastie>:13: this.invariantTuple1 is not a valid implicit value for Invariant[T1] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: diverging implicit expansion for type Invariant[T1]
starting with method invariantFoo

def b = implicitly[Covariant[Foo]]
                  ^
<pastie>:13: covariant is not a valid implicit value for Covariant[Foo] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method invariantFoo of type => Invariant[Foo]
 and method invariantTuple1 of type [T1](implicit evidence$1: Invariant[T1])Invariant[(T1,)]
 match expected type Invariant[A]

def b = implicitly[Covariant[Foo]]
                  ^
<pastie>:13: this.covariant is not a valid implicit value for Covariant[Foo] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method invariantFoo of type => Invariant[Foo]
 and method invariantTuple1 of type [T1](implicit evidence$1: Invariant[T1])Invariant[(T1,)]
 match expected type Invariant[A]

def b = implicitly[Covariant[Foo]]
                  ^
<pastie>:13: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: Covariant[Foo]
```

I have asked about the first two messages as a separate question here [Why does scalac seem to expand implicits too far?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62335023/why-does-scalac-seem-to-expand-implicits-too-far) but I have included the output as it may be relevant to this question.

What I want to know for this question is specifically why does it say:

```
covariant is not a valid implicit value for Covariant[Foo] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method invariantFoo of type => Invariant[Foo]
 and method invariantTuple1 of type [T1](implicit evidence$1: Invariant[T1])Invariant[(T1,)]
 match expected type Invariant[A]
```

Why does `invariantTuple1` match the expected type `Invariant[A]`? Doesn't it know that `A` is `Foo` and so that is not a valid match?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile in 2.13.1 but it does in 2.13.2 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/cX2tVu2dTR2PpC0COL3n6g

Comment: Since expilicit `implicitly[Covariant[Foo]](covariant(a))` compiles it seems this was a bug which is fixed.

Comment: @DmytroMitin do you happen to know the bug number?

Comment: I have a similar problem in Scala 2.12.10.

Comment: You can check 2.13.2 release notes https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.2 It's possible that this one https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8545 (more precisely, there were several issues there).